# Powershellで、他アプリのフォームの値を取得できますか？

Tags: powershell

例えば、メモ帳のエディット（文字入力）部分や、任意のアプリの特定のフォームに表示されている文字列を、powershellから取得できるでしょうか？

環境：
Powershell 5.1
Windows 10
※spy++等は使えません。
※何かをダウンロードすることはできず、Windows標準で付属している機能のみ使えます。

Comment: 質問内容は「取得できるでしょうか？」であり求める答えはできる or できないで正しいですか？ 他の答えを期待しているのであれば、質問文に記載してください。なお「PowerShellで」とありますが逆にPowerShell以外で（つまり他の言語で）の実現方法はわかりますか？

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ [How i can use GetWindowText API function in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40354596/9014308), [How can I get all window handles by a process in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25369285/9014308), [PowerShell, how to grab a window handle of a child process, Visual Studio Project example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36094876/9014308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

できます。
ただし下記のサンプルコードでは、任意のアプリのクラス名と特定のフォームのコントロール名をあらかじめ把握しておく必要があります。

**サンプルコード**

起動しているメモ帳のエディットから文字列を読み取る例です。
任意のアプリの特定のコントロールを読み取る場合は、コード末尾の`"notepad"`と`"Edit"`を適切な値に書き換えてください。

```
$Win32 = &{
Add-Type -Assembly "System.Runtime" 
# ========= C#言語によるWin32Api関数定義(ここから) =========
$cscode = @" 

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent,IntPtr hwndChildafter,string lpszClass,string lpszWindow);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, System.Text.StringBuilder lparam);

public static IntPtr FindWindowByClass(string lpClassName) {
    return FindWindow(lpClassName, null);
}

public static string GetText(IntPtr hwndParent, string lpszClass) {
    int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
    int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
    var hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwndParent, IntPtr.Zero, lpszClass, "");  // コントロールのハンドル
    Console.WriteLine(hwnd);
    var length = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);  // コントロールの文字数
    Console.WriteLine(length);
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(length); /* length分のバッファサイズを確保 */
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, new IntPtr(length+1), sb);
    return sb.ToString();
}
"@
# ========= C#言語によるWin32Api関数定義(ここまで) =========

    return (add-type -memberDefinition $cscode -name "Win32ApiFunctions" -passthru)
}
# クラス名からメモ帳のハンドルを取得
$notepad = $Win32::FindWindowByClass("notepad")
# エディットコントロールの文字列を取得
$s = $Win32::GetText($notepad, "Edit")
# 表示
$s
```

**参考資料**

- [powershellでWin32 APIを利用する（powershell 2.0以上）](https://qiita.com/y-takano/items/cb752ad6a10e550ec92f)
- [C#で他のアプリケーションの値を読み取る。](https://kobazlab.tech/2015/10/01/c%E3%81%A7%E4%BB%96%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E5%80%A4%E3%82%92%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82/)
- [SendMessageのWM_GETTEXTとWM_GETTEXTLENGTHで大幅に文字数が異なる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/38214)

Comment: 早速実行させていただき、即座に動きました。大変助かります。半分諦めかけていたので、希望が見えました。spy++等を使わずにコントロール名を知る方法は頑張って探してみます。